# Reading RINEX formatted streams

Tags: gps, rinex, stream

I'm playing around with a public [NTRIP caster](https://www.use-snip.com/kb/knowledge-base/question-what-is-an-ntrip-caster/) but I'm very new to all this. I'm using [BKG Ntrip Client](https://connect.unavco.org/display/n692103) to read the stream and the file I get has around 45 lines for each sample. Each line begins with the stream code, then `G01`, `G06`, etc. Does that mean the caster can view 45 satellites? I read somewhere that usually only at most 10-15 satellites are visible.

EDIT: Here's the first 2 lines I got:

```
ROBI4 G01 C1C   23698316.588 L1C  124535486.180   15 S1C   40.000 C2W   23698320.484 L2W   97040899.394   15 S2W   22.000 C2X   23698320.966 L2X   97040571.418   15 S2X   39.000 C5X   23698321.324 L5X   92997563.294   15 S5X   46.000
ROBI4 G06 C1C   25005922.799 L1C  131407234.494   13 S1C   34.000 C2W   25005927.678 L2W  102395247.228   13 S2W   17.000 C2X   25005928.446 L2X  102394614.238   15 S2X   35.000 C5X   25005928.232 L5X   98128172.506   15 S5X   40.000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RINEX format specification is either [v3.0x](ftp://igs.org/pub/data/format/rinex303.pdf) or [v2.1x](ftp://igs.org/pub/data/format/rinex210.txt)

The contents of a RINEX file are the (so-called) "raw" observables such as the pseudo-ranges, carrier wave counts, doppler counts, and SNRs for every satellite seen by the GNSS Receiver on the various bands (e.g., L1, L2, L5, and etc).

The NTRIP caster reads/receives "raw" observables from a GNSS Receiver and (re)broadcasts them in an RTCM format. Therefore, you must have been looking at RTCM messages and not RINEX.

Update:
I errorneously stated that the NTRIP Caster by SNIP computes the bias corrections. It does not.

**Reply to Comment**

> *The local caster supports RINEX v3. I've pasted two lines of the output I received. I believe they comply with the RINEX v3 format?*

The two lines in the edited question show what are commonly called the *GNSS observables* in some DIY format, i.e., not RTCM, or RINEX2, or RINEX 3.

An example of GNSS observables in RINEX3 can be seen in [this ZIP file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhPpxcYxPck8gQHaEyLHBuzGlawF). *(Note: Link to expire on 31-MAR-2019.)*

Comment: The local caster supports RINEX v3. I've pasted two lines of the output I received. I believe they comply with the RINEX v3 format?

Comment: Sorry, I saw your reply only just now. In your ZIP file, is each line preceding with `G01`, `G03`, etc. each observed satellite? Does that mean at `> 2018 06 08 02 31  2.0000000  0 14`, your rover could track 14 different satellites?

Comment: @JohnM. Yes. At epoch "2018-JUNE-08 02:31:2.0 UTC" (excluding leap seconds up to that date/time, which is 18 secs), the rover recorded observables from 14 satellites.